# csv to database c#

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

The following code i believe work to upload csv file to database with the following format:

csv format:

john,anderson,m

1. It will record to TableRef table with insert statement (Done)
2. Need to insert custId and RefId in the BulkImportDetails based on how many list record in csv. Currently it only insert 1 record.

table 1: TableRef (guid refid(pk, not null), taskname, taskdescription)
table 2: BulkImportDetails (guid custid (pk, not null), guid refid(fk, not null, firstname, surname, age)

how i can insert information based on csv format to both table, please advise. thank you

```
        /// <summary>
        /// Process the file supplied and process the CSV to a dynamic datatable
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="fileName">String</param>
        /// <returns>DataTable</returns>
        private static DataTable ProcessCSV(string fileName)
    {

        string connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString;
        int AppID = Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AppID"]);
        Guid ReferralID = Guid.NewGuid();
        DateTime date = DateTime.Now;
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
        {
            conn.Open();

            using (SqlCommand cmd =
            new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO TestTable VALUES(" +
                "refid, @ServerID, @AppID, @CreateDate, @CreatedBy, @CreateDescription, @Description)", conn))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@refid", ReferralID);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ServerID", 2);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AppID", AppID);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CreateDate", date);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CreatedBy", "Create by bulk insert");
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CreateDescription", "Create by bulk insert");
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Description", "Create by bulk insert");


                int rows = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                //rows number of record got inserted
            }


        }

        //Set up our variables 
        string Feedback = string.Empty;
        string line = string.Empty;
        string[] strArray;
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        DataRow row;

        // work out where we should split on comma, but not in a sentance
        Regex r = new Regex(",(?=(?:[^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*(?![^\"]*\"))");

        //Set the filename in to our stream
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fileName);

        //Read the first line and split the string at , with our regular express in to an array
        line = sr.ReadLine();
        strArray = r.Split(line);

        //For each item in the new split array, dynamically builds our Data columns. Save us having to worry about it.

        Array.ForEach(strArray, s => dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn()));
        dt.Columns.Add("CustID", Type.GetType("System.Guid"));
        dt.Columns.Add("Refid", Type.GetType("System.Guid"));
        dt.Columns["CustID"].SetOrdinal(3);
        dt.Columns["Refid"].SetOrdinal(4);
        //Read each line in the CVS file until it's empty
        while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            row = dt.NewRow();

            //add our current value to our data row
            row["CustID"] = Guid.NewGuid();
            row["Refid"] = ReferralID;

            row.ItemArray = r.Split(line);
            dt.Rows.Add(row);
        }
        dt.Columns["CustID"].SetOrdinal(0);

        dt.Columns["Refid"].SetOrdinal(1);
        //Tidy Streameader up
        sr.Dispose();

        //return a the new DataTable
        return dt;


    }




        /// <summary>
        /// Take the DataTable and using WriteToServer(DataTable) send it all to the database table "BulkImportDetails" in one go
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="dt">DataTable</param>
        /// <returns>String</returns>
        private static String ProcessBulkCopy(DataTable dt)
        {
            string Feedback = string.Empty;
            string connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DataBaseConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

            //make our connection and dispose at the end    
            using(  SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
            {
                //make our command and dispose at the end
                using (var copy = new SqlBulkCopy(conn))
                {

                        //Open our connection
                        conn.Open();

                        ///Set target table and tell the number of rows
                        copy.DestinationTableName = "BulkImportDetails";
                        copy.BatchSize = dt.Rows.Count;
                        try
                        {
                            //Send it to the server
                            copy.WriteToServer(dt);
                            Feedback = "Upload complete";
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            Feedback = ex.Message;
                        }
                }
            }

            return Feedback;
       }
```

Comment: Why don't you use SQL Management Studio? It contains wizards to import csv files.

Comment: Hi Zippy, Thank you for your response. But i need to upload the csv file from application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified the code as the following:
http://arranmaclean.wordpress.com/2010/07/20/net-mvc-upload-a-csv-file-to-database-with-bulk-upload/#comment-188